# Is iter++->empty() a legal expression?

Tags: c++, post-increment

Is `iter++->empty()` a legal expression?

`iter` is an `iterator` of a `vector` of `string`s.

I am asking because considering the precedence of the operators both `->` and `()` should precede the postfix increment but I really don't know how the operands should be grouped.

On my compiler it works (the expression yields the `empty()` result for the first string and `iter` points to the second string) but I'm still wondering if it is Undefined Behaviour.

**Edit**

I just found the solution (I think):

`iter++->empty()` should be the same as `(*iter++).empty()`

therefore considering associativity and precedence rules the grouping should be:

`(((*(iter++)).empty) ())`

Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's legal, but don't do it.

Asking yourself this question is reason enough to break it into two statements:

```
iter->empty();
iter++;
```

Comment: thank you. I am a newcomer to C++. This is a question in my primer and considering precedence, associativity and order of evaluation rules I was really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the iterator `it` is valid, the expression `it++->empty()` is well-defined

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `iter->empty()` is a valid statement, the answer is yes. The post-increment operator doesn't change the type of `iter`, is simply increments it after the `empty()` method has been performed.

However, I'd recommend splitting it up into two statements, as (especially post-) increment statements often make your code less clear. So why not go for:

```
iter->empty();
iter++;
```