# C++: why is iter++->empty() legal?

Tags: c++, pointers, post-increment

Exercise 4.20 of *C++ Primer, 5e* asks whether the expression `iter++->empty();` is legal. Assume that `iter` is a `vector<string>::iterator`.

This expression is legal. I compiled it with gcc, and the answers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765623/is-iter-empty-a-legal-expression) on Stack Overflow have addressed this much. However, I'm confused as to *why* it is legal.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765654/2227966) to a similar question gives the following as an equivalent pair of expressions:

```
iter->empty();
iter++;
```

The operator precedence table in my book lists `->` as having higher precedence than the postfix `++` operator. This matches the explicit order of operations in the equivalent code above. However, I am used to seeing operators apply to whatever is right next to them. In the case of `->`, I expected the compiler would to apply it to `++` (by itself, without `iter`) and throw an error. In other words, I tried to parenthesize the original expression as `iter(++->empty());`, which is obviously illegal.

So, it seems like c++ requires compilers to parse expressions in a more complex way than just parenthesizing based on precedence and associativity. Is that right? If there is an easy way to explain how this actually happens, I would like to know about it.

Comment: [Why do you think it shouldn't be?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) Which container type is `iter` from?

Comment: [My table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says they got equal precedence.

Comment: Do be careful to avoid confusing "legal" as in "compiles because it is syntactically valid" with "legal" as in "has defined behaviour".

Comment: I would think the "obviously illegal" approach you think is logical would be a strong argument for why it doesn't do that; that attempt at parsing doesn't make sense, since you can't attach an operator to an operator, it has to attach to an expression, and so `iter++` has to bind first. Also, your book is wrong, or you're misreading it; [postfix `++` has the *same* precedence as `->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) (prefix `++` has lower precedence than either, but it's not involved here).

Comment: Your equivalent expression is incorrect too, since `iter` must be incremented before `empty` is called. Beginner often get confused about when the pre and post increment side effects occur.

Comment: Although looking at the answer you linked it doesn't say the two expressions are equivalent, it just says you should prefer the second version.

Comment: @john I read your comment wrong.  Deleting.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess it could be clearer, too late now

Comment: Just to be clear about this, the equivalent sequence would be something like this `auto temp = iter; iter++; temp->empty();`

Comment: I've looked at the precedence table in the C++ Primer and it is definitely wrong and even meaningless on several counts. Postfix ++ has right associativity? Really? I'd like to try what they were smoking. How do you ever interpret this statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `++` and `->` have the same precedence and have left to aright associativity.  That means that `iter++` is executed first, and then `->empty()` is applied to the result of `iter++`, which is just `iter` (from before the increment) since it is postfix increment.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. This contradicts the table page 166 of C++ Primer, 5th edition. Any chance this was a recent change to the standard?

Comment: @KevinBradner AFAIK, it's always been like this.

Comment: @KevinBradner Having different precedence for different postfix unary operators wouldn't make a lot of sense (same for prefix ones).

Comment: I was assuming it had to do with associativity. According to my reference, (->) is left associative, and postfix (++) is right associative. I'm not sure how these resolve if the operators are at the same precedence level.

Comment: @KevinBradner this [table](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-primer-fifth/9780133053043/ch04lev1sec12.html)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, that seems like the same one.

Comment: @KevinBradner According to cppreference, both have same associativity. I don't think associativity even makes sense for unary operators.

Comment: @KevinBradner I've found a PDF version of the book [here](http://www.charleshouserjr.com/Cplus2.pdf) but am not finding the table at page 166.  Do you know what section it is in?

Comment: @NathanOliver the section is 4.12. Note that it matches the link provided by AlanBirtles above.

Comment: @KevinBradner Thanks.  Looks like a bad table to me.

Comment: I guess the line above postfix increment is an error or just there to separate the left and right associative operators, overall not the clearest table, the rest looks correct

Comment: @HolyBlackCat fair point about the associativity of ++. This link seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961351/does-it-make-sense-for-unary-operators-to-be-associative